# Ubuntu nginx cert is showing unsecure

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https

i generate a cert on ubuntu (nginx), Everything works fine, but when i load the page it is showing me unsecure. I also tried to run several ssl server test and  was trying to find anything useful, but unsuccessfully. Still showing unsecure

Any ideas? What should i do?

Link for my website: [website](https://vgocaseking.cz/)

SSL report: [report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=vgocaseking.cz)

Comment: According to digicert, your cert is fine. What specifically does your browser say is insecure? https://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: First of all thank you for reply, My app is polling every few seconds and it is polling via https, but in console i am getting error: cert authority invalid so it didnt get the data. You can see these errors in console on my page

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors. It might be something on your network. Are you behind any sort of firewall or filtering proxy or network filter?

Comment: Are you really seeing clear console? No i do not

Comment: Yes, it didn't complain about anything

Comment: "My app is polling every few seconds and it is polling via https, but in console i am getting error: cert authority invalid" it means that your polling application probably does not have the proper CA certificate in its trust store and hence is unable to validate your website certificate. It is not the website certificate/setup that has a problem.

Comment: I generate a ssl cer using cerbot it was free so maybe it is not valid or i dont know